# Sessionization based on events and not timestamps with mySQL

Tags: mysql, session

I got a table that I need to create sessions for. In this table we have the user logged and the event that happened within the application. These sessions needs to be split by when the event entry is a login. Any entry with the same user that happens after a login is part of the same session until a new login event entry occurs.

So two cols User and Event, and the split of a session grouped by User and when `Event = 'app:login'` needs to be added to the outcome.

[I have created this very basic visual representation of my goal. Not sure if it helps mending the gaps of my explanation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JofpO.png)

I was thinking something along the lines of using GROUP BY and then joining that result to then concat it on each row.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by frankensteining together some random sql till I got my result.

```
SELECT *
  , "userid" || '_' || SUM(new_session)
  OVER (PARTITION BY "userid" ORDER BY "datetime") AS session_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN "eventname" = 'login:bo:success'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as new_session
  FROM
    "TEST_events_prepared_2"
) s1
```